# Set Global Variables in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've set up some global variables, with default values and have tried to access them with ${ID}, ${PRJ}, ${RELEASE} but no success whatsoever.

ID -> ${JOB_NAME} | cut -d ‘_’ -f 1

PRJ -> ${JOB_NAME} | cut -d ‘_’ -f 2

RELEASE ->${JOB_NAME} | cut -d ‘_’ -f 3

Jenkins Job Name format

ID_PRJ_ RELEASE

E.g. 1234_AngularJS_Q1

Answer (score 0):

Use normal quotes and assign with a sub-process:

```
ID=$(echo "${JOB_NAME}" | cut -d'_' -f1)
```

You can also use shell internals (avoiding a call to cut), with

```
ID="${JOB_NAME//*_}"
RELEASE="${JOB_NAME//*_}"
```

The PRJ will need 2 steps or something like `sed`.
But before implementing this, make sure that the PRJ will not contain underscores too, e.g. 1235_Hello_World_1.0.

Comment: But still can't access them with ${ID}, ${PRJ}, ${RELEASE} from the Shell Scripts.

Comment: Please note that these variables are under the “Manage Jenkins > Global Properties” section and managed centrally.

Comment: When you set the values in a script, finish the script and start another script all settings of the first script are lost. When ${JOB_NAME} is available in your scripts, you can put the extra assignments in an "include-file", and just include that file in your script. Including is done with `source`, something like `source /usr/local/bin/jenkensutils.inc` as the second line of your script (the first one will be `#!/bin/bash`). You can abbreviate `source` with a dot and choose another path or filename (I prefer a folder `shlib`).